# How to use different type of selector

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

so i have recently been working with selenium and im just starting and i have ran into an issue if i have a website like this:

```
<html>
    <Button value="MyButton">press me!</button>
</html>
```

how would i press the button with the value `MyButton`

i have tried using the class name and the id for the solution but it just pops up for this code:

```
eighth = driver.find_element_by_class_name("MyButtonClass")
eighth.click()
```

with the error:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".MyButtonClass"}
```

Comment: There is no `class="MyButtonClass"`, why would you expect that to work?

Comment: its just a example